# Asp.net select all in checkboxlist using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, combobox

I have a checkbox for select/deselect all elements in a Asp.net checkboxlist.

All work fine for first select deselect click, after, when I click on select all the checkboxlist not render the checked value. 
If I inspect the code using google chrome tool, I can see that checkboxlist elements have 
checked="checked" but I can't see the flag checked!!

aspx code:

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="selAllckb_canone" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Seleziona tutti" />
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ckb_canone" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" >
            <asp:ListItem>Gennaio</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Febbraio</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Marzo</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Aprile</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Maggio</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Giugno</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Luglio</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Agosto</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Settembre</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Ottobre</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Novembre</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Dicembre</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

jquery code:

```
function sel_all(id_selAll, idcombolist) {
        $("#" + id_selAll).bind("click", function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("INPUT[id^='" + idcombolist + "_']").attr("checked", "checked");
            } else {
                $("INPUT[id^='" + idcombolist + "_']").removeAttr("checked");
            }
        });
        $("INPUT[id^='" + idcombolist + "_']").bind("click", function () {
            if ($("INPUT[id^='" + idcombolist + "_']:checked").length == $("INPUT[id^='" + idcombolist + "_']").length) {
                $("#" + id_selAll).attr("checked", "checked");
            } else {
                $("#" + id_selAll).removeAttr("checked");
            }
        });

 $(function () {

        sel_tutti("selAllckb_canone", "ckb_canone");

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the checked status instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$("INPUT[id^='" + idcombolist + "_']").prop("checked", this.checked);
```

Read: [Prop Vs Attrs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)

Try

```
function sel_all(id_selAll, idcombolist) {
    var $chcks = $("INPUT[id^='" + idcombolist + "_']"),
        $all = $("#" + id_selAll);
    $all.on("click", function () {
        $chcks.prop("checked", this.checked);
    });
    $chcks.on("click", function () {
        $all.prop("checked", $chcks.not(':checked').length == 0);
    });

    $(function () {
        sel_tutti("selAllckb_canone", "ckb_canone");
    });
```